# Property Initialization error with Function Type

Tags: swift

I'm in the process of learning Swift and working on applying a callback pattern to a class as practice and running into an issue I cannot get past (Build Error)

```
override init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience init(picker: UIPickerView) {
    self.init()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
}

var _selectedCallback:  (String) -> Void        

func onItemSelected(callback: (String) -> Void) {
    self._selectedCallback = callback
}
```

The above snippet places a compiler error on `super.init()` with the error message

> "Property 'self._selectedCallback' not initialized at super.init call"

.

Now, I understand that all local variables have to have values assigned to them; however, how would I initialize the function type of _selectedCallback? Examples I've seen has something like the following:

```
var _selectedCallback:  (String) -> Void = test

func test(message: String { }
```

The above snippet returns a compile error of

> "'String' is not a subtype of "

I feel like I'm missing something simple, I just can't find it.  That or I'm doing it wrong and need to find a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give it a default value, like this:

```
var _selectedCallback: (String) -> Void = { _ in return }
```

Or, you could make it an optional that is set to `nil` by default, and set it later:

```
var _selectedCallback: ((String) -> Void)?
```

I generally prefer the second option, as `Optional`s are intended to represent the possibility that there might not actually be a value, which is the situation that you are in.